# Compact BaseForm Alternative that Extends to Bases > 36

Tags: recreational-mathematics

I recently created a [document](http://chesswanks.com/num/a256112.pdf) listing the terms of OEIS sequence [A256112](https://oeis.org/A256112) in `BaseForm`. Term #164 and #165 at the end of the document are the two solutions in base 35. As I continue to search for additional terms in the sequence I am about to hit the `BaseForm` limitation of bases needing to be integers less than 37.

A viable alternative is to list these numbers as comma-separated `IntegerDigits`. I would prefer something more compact, say a `BaseForm` that incorporates the Greek alphabet starting at base 37. I don't know how to do that. Or, if it was possible to enclose each digit of an `IntegerDigits` list in a standard-sized square, that might look ok as an output. I'm asking for a good-looking, compact `BaseForm` alternative that extends the current limitation to bases beyond 36.

Comment: (in before every character in Unicode gets used as a digit...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using Chinese characters:

```
chineseRange = CharacterRange[19968, 40959];
symbols = Join[ToString /@ Range[0, 9], chineseRange];
StringJoin[symbols[[# + 1]] & /@ IntegerDigits[31805256011396003, 72]]
(* ""丢2丰为丛8一世丙"" *)
```

You can find character ranges here: https://unicode-table.com/en/blocks/control-character

Using Cyrillic:

```
cyrillicRange = CharacterRange[1024, 1279];
symbols = Join[ToString /@ Range[0, 9], cyrillicRange];
StringJoin[symbols[[# + 1]] & /@ IntegerDigits[31805256011396003, 72]]
(* "Т2акЛ8ЀЖЙ" *)
```

More sensibly, going up to base 61 gives you 0-9, a-z, and alpha-omega in lower case

```
lcGreekRange = CharacterRange[945, 969];
symbols = Join[ToString /@ Range[0, 9], CharacterRange["a", "z"], lcGreekRange];
StringJoin[symbols[[# + 1]] & /@ IntegerDigits[31805256011396003,Length@symbols]]
(* "2θτdy28φν1" *)
```

Comment: "up to base 61" - and this is not even including the variant Greek letters. Still, I think after going through three or four alphabets, trying to make every digit representable as a single character seems untenable.

Comment: Can we add the base subscript to the end of the string?

Comment: Yes: `str = "1234abc"; base = 195; Subscript[str, base]`

Comment: :) I meant for you to adjust your answer with the subscripts but I'll accept it regardless.